# Variable vs global variable

Tags: vimrc

In `h: internal-variables` it mentions the "global" variable which is prefixed by `g:`. What would be the difference between:

```
let g:var = "xyz"
```

And:

```
let var = "xyz"
```

Does the absence of a prefix mean `g:`, or are they two different things?

Comment: Depends on context: the scope default to different things depending on where its used (script local in scripts, function local in functions, i think. Plus there are buffer and window local, which are never defaults)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In VimScript all variables have a scope. Or, better to say, they are organized into `:h Dictionaries` with reserved names. So `echo g:` is a perfectly valid command.

There are the following scopes (dictionaries) in no particular order:

1. `g:` Global
2. `s:` Script-local (like "static" in C)
3. `l:` Function-local
4. `a:` Function argument
5. `v:` Vim internal
6. `b:` Buffer local
7. `w:` Window local
8. `t:` Tab local

If scope is not given then `v:` is searched. If there's no such variable in `v:` then it's either `s:` or `l:` depending on the execution context. Also, while on the command line it's `g:`, as, obviously, neither `s:` nor `l:` applies in interactive mode.

Comment: thanks, so if I execute `:let var = "new"` then that goes into the `g:` dict because I haven't qualified its prefix/namespace?

Comment: Interactively? Yes. You can always check it with `echo g:var` or `echo get(g:, 'var')`

Comment: I did not know for _nothing_ that could be interpreted as `s:`... oO BTW, there is also a little issue with lambdas: we have to be explicit to use global variables, even interactively, while it's not the case in `echo map(somelist, 'v:val > globalthreshold')`.

Comment: @LucHermitte Lambda is a kind of closure, so it's normal when it inherits default meaning of `l:`, `a:` and `s:` as if executing in the outer scope. However, it's really strange that "global" lambda does not have `g:` by default. Should it be called inconsistency or bug?

Comment: @Matt, I'd say _inconsistency_.