# Understanding local (s, l, and a) variables

Tags: vimrc

From the docs, local variables are defined as:

- `script-variable    s:     Local to a :source'ed Vim script.`
- `function-argument  a:     Function argument (only inside a function).`
- `local-variable     l:     Local to a function.`

It seems that `a` is the simplest and most narrow -- this can never be user-defined within a function and is only used to reference the variables that were passed to a given function. In other words, I cannot do something like `a:name = "Tom"`, and its the only variable type that cannot be defined on the left-hand side.

What would be the difference then between `l` and `s`? As far as I understand, `l:var` can only be done inside a function and is illegal to use outside of a function, and once the function is done the `l:var` variable is discarded. And then `s:var` I'm not too clear on at all (for example, why can't I call this from the command-line within the function its being used?).

Comment: As @Matt said [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25910/626): script local variables are as static variables in C. In vimscript language, ther name is quite explicit: their [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) is restricted to the script they belong to. They cannot be referenced outside. And as usual with programming with every other programming language that I know, local variables cannot be used outside the scope of their function.

Comment: @LucHermitte -- I see, the only other thing I thought odd was when I define a variable in, for example, `.vimrc` it adds that variable into `g:` rather than `s:`. Why does a variable defined outside a function in a script belong to the `g:` scoope?

Comment: It's like how it works in C. Variables defined at file (_translation unit_ actually) level that aren't explicitly declared static are global variables. Vim follows the same _rule_.