# Wonder the scope of the output of the vim command :tags

Tags: tags

When I invoke `:tags` command in vim, the result varies depending on vim windows.
So I wonder the scope of the result of the vim command `:tags`.
I guess it would be one of below:

1. `g:` Global
2. `s:` Script-local (like "static" in C)
3. `l:` Function-local
4. `a:` Function argument
5. `v:` Vim internal
6. `b:` Buffer local
7. `w:` Window local
8. `t:` Tab local

The above is from [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25898/variable-vs-global-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:help :tags` prints the current state of the `:help tag-stack`, which is indeed **window-local** (tough the documentation is sadly not explicit about it).

But the scopes you listed in your question only matter for *variables*. They are pretty much meaningless in the context of `:tags`, and thus irrelevant.

That said, if you want to save the tag stack of the current window to a variable, then it makes the most sense to make that variable window-local with the appropriate scope:

```
let w:tag_stack = gettagstack()
```

Other than that, scopes are irrelevant.

Comment: I maybe understood half of what you said. I received that you answered the scope is similar to the windows local. What I don't understand is why you said irrelevant. I will study the :help :tags and :help tag-stack. Thank you again!

Comment: @Jumogehn what do you think the `:tags` command does? Maybe you are misunderstanding it. Tags are not variables.

Comment: @Friedrich Watching the tag-stack value varies depending on vim windows gave me a question - The tag-stack is not globally behave. And they seemed to belong to each windows. So I guessed tag-stack is maybe behaves similar to a variable and it maybe have scopes... And still I guess the tag-stack is maintained by some variables and the variables may have scope and that is why the tag-stack appears differently on windows